# Find left table and right table when we join more than 2 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have three tables here one of them is a Country table second one is a city table and the third one is a customer table, and I am writing a query here like this

```
SELECT country.country_name_eng, city.city_name, customer.customer_name
FROM Country
LEFT JOIN city ON city.country_id = country.id
LEFT JOIN customer ON customer.city_id = city.id
```

I want to know here who is the left table of the customer table and who is the left table of the city table as well as who is the right table of the country table and who is the right table of the customer table

Comment: I have not idea what you are asking, please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: The table left to the `JOIN` is on left. In your case, left of Customer is the query output that you would see if you hadnt had `LEFT JOIN customer ON customer.city_id = city.id`.  Left of the city is Country table and hence right table of country is city. There isnt anything `JOIN`ed after customer and hence there isnt anything right to it. Think of `JOIN` in the middle for you to identify what is left/right to it.

Comment: just i wanted to know who is the left table of customer table

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` more means that the data to the *left* of the join won't be "lost" when the `JOIN` finds no rows, @coder. In your query above, for `[dbo.]customer` that would the data from **both** `[dbo.]Country` *and* `[dbo.]city`.

Comment: Perhaps you are also interested in orphaned customers ie where customer record exists but not allocated to a city and/or country in which case a FULL JOIN might be appropriate  but it's not clear from your question what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Left' is *always* the table at the left of the `JOIN` keyword, no matter if left, right, inner or full outer join, analogously 'right'.

Left and right *joins*, though, have different semantics:

With a normal (inner) join a data row is only added if there's a matching entry in *both* tables, e.g. if you `JOIN ON l.id = r.id` then if `l` contains an `id` with value 7 a row for is only added if there's a matching `id` with value 7 in `r` as well (and vice versa).

A *left* (outer) join instead adds a row for `id` 7 in `l` even if there's no matching `id` in `r` – then the corresponding columns for table `r` are filled with nulls.

Analogously a *right* (outer) join, all entries of `r` are added with nulls for `l`'s columns if no matching entry found.

A *full* outer join is a combination of left and right outer join, any entry of `l` and `r` is used with nulls on either side for the counter part if none exists.

In your concrete query you'd list all countries even if there don't exist any cities – and if they *do* exist, for each country all of them even if there don't exist any customers there. In the latter case the columns for the customer are all filled with null values, and if no city exists either, *additionally* all city columns.